# Pandas: How select rows by multiple criteria (if not nan and equals to specific value)

Tags: python, pandas, selection, nan

I have a DataFrame

| index | Street | House | Building |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 20 | a |
| 2 | ABC | 20 | b |
| 3 | ABC | 21 | NaN |
| 4 | BCD | 2 | 1 |

Need to create a multiple selection from this DataFrame:

- *If Street == str_filter*;
- *If House == house_filter*;
- *If Building == build_filter* AND *If Building is not NULL*;

I've already tried `df[(df['Street'] == str_filter) & (df['House'] == house_filter) & ((df['Building'] == build_filter) & (pd.notnull(df['Building'])))`

But doesn't lead to a result I particularly want to see. I have to check if the Building value is not NaN and if it's true select the row with the certain Building num. However, I also want to select the row if it has NaN value for the Building but also meets other criteria.

Another idea was to create lists for the set of filter values and the set of this values meeting pd.notnull criteria:

```
filter_values = [str_filter, house_filter, build_filter] 
notnull_values = [pd.notnull(entry) for entry in filter_values]
```

This one doesn't meet the performance criteria, because I have extremely huge DataFrame and creating additional lists with additional filtering will lead to the out-performance. Possible solution may lay in the `df.loc` function, but I don't know how to realise it.

To summarise, the problem is the following: **How to create multiple selection in pandas with conditions for NaN values?**

UPD: It seems that the function I have to use is `df[... & (df['Building'] == 'a' if pd.notnull(df['Building']))]` using an analogy with lambda apply trick

Comment: Do you have an example of what kind of filter you want to apply? My intuition tells me this could be solved with masks.

Comment: @Oddaspa Sure! I want to find all duplicates on the certain columns, but it seems that df.duplicated doesn't work for entries with NaN values. So under the filters I mean certain values i.e. df[(df['Building'] == 'a') & (pd.notnull(df['Building'])))]

Comment: I see you updated the question. Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in a comment that you also had issues with duplicates, I've added an option to remove these.

I have recreated your dataset with this, and added a duplicate.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Street" : ["ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "BCD", "ABC"],
    "House" : [20, 20, 21, 2, 21],
    "Building" : ['a', 'b', np.NaN, 1, np.NaN]
})
```

To remove duplicates from your dataset you can simply run this block:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

I am assuming that your filter might be a whitelist of strings or numbers that you want to include in your final dataset. Therefore I took the liberty of defining a filter as this:

```
street_filter = ["ABC", "BCD"]
```

To clean the dataset you could then use this method:

```
def get_mask(df, street_filter, house_filter, building_filter):
  not_na_mask = df['Building'].notna()
  # hopefully smaller df to query
  df = df[not_na_mask]

  street_mask = df['Street'].apply(lambda x: x in street_filter)
  df = df[street_mask]

  house_mask = df['House'].apply(lambda x: x in house_filter)
  df = df[house_mask]

  building_mask = df['Building'].apply(lambda x: x in building_filter)
  return df[building_mask]
```

### Example

```
street_filter = ["ABC", "BCD"]
house_filter = [20, 21]
building_filter = ["a"]
get_mask(df, street_filter, house_filter, building_filter)

    Street  House   Building
 0  ABC     20      a
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple way to do it would be this:

```
if df[df['Building'].isnull()].empty:
    df[df['Street'] == str_filter][df['House'] == house_filter][df['Building'] == build_filter]
else:
    df[df['Street'] == str_filter][df['House'] == house_filter][df['Building'].isnull()]
```

I'm not sure if this would satisfy your performance requirements?

Comment: I've tried your code. It works perfect for multiple conditions, but fails when I try to select rows with NaN in Building field

Comment: So you want the Building field to be equal to NaN? I thought you wanted to exclude the NaN values. @sailestim

Comment: I have recently updated the code. Just saying in case you have only tried the code in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the latest one. So, all I want is just a simple dataframe subset selection of equal values including NaN values. Taking my example, I want select 3rd row. If there was no NaN value at the Building field, I would use `df[df['Building'] == 'a']`. But it doesn't work with NaN, so I have to use some kind of exception like my UPD in the question: `df[(df['Building'] == 'a' if pd.notnull(df['Building']) else df['Building'] == math.nan ]`

Comment: Ok so as I understand it you want to select all NaN values in building but if there are none then you want to select from building then you want to select where [building == "Some String"]. I'll work on an answer for you. I'll be a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to google/search on stack for if-else pandas subset selection, but found no help

Comment: Let me know if the new answer is satisfactory, otherwise I'll keep trying xD